# Visual Studio .NET Windows Form Project does not work after deployment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a Visual studio .NET 4.5 Windows Form Application.

I am trying to connect to a usb modem, reading/writing data to it(using USBHIDDRIVER). It works fine when I run the project inside visual studio. But does not work when I  run .exe file from bin/debug or bin/release or make a installer and install it.

Please someone suggest me if I need to change/add any settings to visual studio to work it outside visual studio.

Comment: Maybe it is a permission problem? Try running it as administrator. And try to get an exception that cause the problem.

Comment: I fixed some exceptions changing visual studio exception settings(break on user-unhandled exceptions). Still it the same problem. @Winney

Comment: I ran both visual studio and .exe in bin/debug as administrator. But same problem. It only works when I run it inside visual studio. :( @Icardi

Comment: It's kind of hard helping you out without seeing an exception...

Comment: I am getting no exception @bump

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to try:

1. Update/build your code before you publish it or run it.
2. Run it as admin (could be because of permissions)
3. Go back and add error checking into your code if you haven't, it's hard to help without getting an actual error
4. Make sure you have all dependencies (all your DLLs and Libraries) in the right spot(s) when you run it.
5. Restart your device/computer
6. Check your net-frame versions (make sure they match what you developed for and what you are running)
7. Let me know if you can find any exceptions or errors (even minor things in your code) and we can be of allot more help! Good luck, let me know if any of these work